# I tried this code but I am having problem to save data in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, crud

I am using Django to create an e-commerce application. I am trying to save user data in my database but it is not working. I am using MySQL for database.

I have already tried using MySQL raw query and forms as well.

This is my template that takes the user input.

**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='POST' action="/demo">

    {% csrf_token %}    
    <div class='main'>
    <label>Full Name</label>

    {{ form.fname }}
    <label>UserName</label>
    {{ form.uname }}
    <label>Email</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <label>mobile</label>
    {{ form.mobile }}
    <label>Password</label>
    {{ form.password }}

    <button type="submit">Click me!</button>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My model:

```
    class new_table(models.Model):
          fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
          uname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
          mobile = models.IntegerField()
          email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
          password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

          class Meta:
             db_table = 'new_table'
```

My view for saving the form:
    views.py

```
def demo_action(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
     form = NewTableForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            return redirect()
        except:
            pass    
else:   
    form = NewTableForm()
return render(request,"demo.html",{'form':form})
```

My form:

```
forms.py

   class NewTableForm(forms.ModelForm): 
         class Meta:
             model = new_table
             fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: can you show the view for saving the data?

Comment: i have only this view what to do next

Comment: can you show error log

Comment: Oh sorry. I did not notice the views. Let me have a look at it.

Comment: it's not showing any error

Comment: it's not showing any errors @c.grey

Comment: i think it must be forms errors

Comment: Is it that you are using () in your if statement? Or is it a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing forms.py error while submitting form

try this

```
def demo_action(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = NewTableForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            return redirect()
        except:
            pass
   else:
      print(form.errors)
      form = NewTableForm(request.POST)  
      return render(request,"demo.html",{'form':form})  
else:   
    form = NewTableForm()
return render(request,"demo.html",{'form':form})
```

in template

```
<form method='POST' action="/demo">

    {% csrf_token %}    
    <div class='main'>
    <label>Full Name</label>
    Error = {{form.errors}}
    {{ form.fname }}
    <label>UserName</label>
    {{ form.uname }}
    <label>Email</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <label>mobile</label>
    {{ form.mobile }}
    <label>Password</label>
    {{ form.password }}

    <button type="submit">Click me!</button>

    </div>
    </form>
```

hope it helps